# Print A Pandas Data Frame to a Text File (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large data file like this

```
 Words
 One
 Two
 Three
 ....
 Threethousand
```

I am trying to print this list to a text file with this code:

```
 df1 = df[['Words']]
 with open('atextfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
         print(df1, file=outfile)
```

But what happens is that it doesn't print out the whole DF, it ends up looking like this:

```
 Words
 One
 Two
 Three
 ....
 Threethousand
 Fourthousand
 Fivethousand
```

How can I print out the whole DF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `to_string` to do this, it doesn't abbreviate like the printing:

```
df['Words'].to_string('atextfile.txt')
# or
df[['Words']].to_string('atextfile.txt')
```